# Story of a child who fell in honey and died?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, yoreh-deah, honey

I remember learning in Yoreh Deah about a halachic case about a child who fell into honey and died, and the Tosfos Yom Tov declared the honey not kosher. Where is that story found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Beth Hillel (YD 103:2) of [R. Hillel Herz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_ben_Naphtali_Zevi) brings it down from the work Torath ha-Asham of [R. Gershon Shaul Lipmann Heller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom-Tov_Lipmann_Heller) (aka the Tosafoth Y"T) who wrote about the incident occurring in Kraków, Poland. The Friedman edition of the SA with the Beth Hillel printed in the back has a footnote that states:

> בתורת האשם שלפנינו לא נמצא זה

Indicating that our editions of R. Heller's Torath ha-Asham do not have the story. Nevertheless the incident seems to have entered the halakhic discourse. You can find a list of sources on the topic here:

- [נפל תינוק ליורה של דבש - מעשה בתוס' י"ט](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=65752&st=&pgnum=327&hilite=)

Comment: Thank you .....